# How to get around this error related to a CASE statement in my ORDER BY syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am querying a linked server.

My T-SQL query stands as follows:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT 

[EMP_CODE],
[NAME],
[ADDRESS]

FROM [xxx.xxx.xx].[HR].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE]

WHERE [EMP_CODE] IN (
'A0025',
'A0045',
'B0008',
 ...
 ...
 'A0096' )

ORDER BY
CASE [EMP_CODE]

WHEN 'A0025' THEN 1
WHEN 'A0045' THEN 2
WHEN 'B0008' THEN 3
...
...
WHEN 'A0096' THEN 68

END
```

My issue is that I am getting the following error message when running the above T_SQL query:

```
"Case expressions may only be nested to level 10."
```

How can I get around this error?

Comment: I see no nested `case` expressions, so I'm a bit baffled on how this code could be generating this error.

Comment: Is the linked server marked as collation compatible? If not, that could lead to some funky rewrites. Also, try introducing the `CASE` expression in a subquery first before ordering on it. If all else fails, introduce a table in a subquery (using `VALUES`) and `JOIN` on that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I missed the WHERE part in my query. I have updated same. I don't know if that missing part is the cause of the issue.

Comment: The reason for the error is explained here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42850/3690 (cc @JeroenMostert)

Comment: You could probably greatly simplify that case expression with some simple tricks. If we assume that you generally order by the actual string, then simply move these "normal" values out of the case expression and keep the special ones. E.g., `order by case EMP_CODE when 'A0096' then 1 else 0 end, EMP_CODE;` It would be far better to formally capture your special ordering values in a table that can be joined - making changes to the order vastly easier and simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the nested `case` expressions are coming from.  But an alternative formulation would use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM [xxx.xxx.xx].[HR].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE] e LEFT JOIN
     (VALUES ('A0025', 1), ('A0045', 2), ('B0008', 3), . . .)
     ) v(emp_code, ord)
     ON e.emp_code = v.emp_code
ORDER BY COALESCE(v.ord, 1000000)
```